# ¿Cómo crear una tabla factura en mi base de datos con MySQL, sin obtener el error 1068?

Tags: mysql

Teniendo en cuenta los siguientes detalles:

|  |  |
| --- | --- |
| letra | char y Primary Key |
| numero | int y Primary Key |
| fecha | date |
| monto | double |

La creé de la siguiente manera:

```
Create table facturas_1 (
    letra Char(1) Primary Key,
    numero Int Primary Key,
    fecha Date,
    monto Double
);
```

Cuando la quiero crear me da:

> error 1068 multiple primary key defined

Answer (score 2):

Si quieres que tanto letra como numero sean claves primarias, debes definir una clave primaria compuesta, puedes hacer esto de la siguiente manera:

```
CREATE TABLE facturas_1 (
  letra CHAR(1),
  numero INT,
  fecha DATE,
  monto DOUBLE,
  PRIMARY KEY (letra, numero)
);
```